# What is the difference of tex-mode and latex-mode and LaTeX-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am configuring AUCTeX in emacs.

Most of the configurations are put in a LaTeX-mode-hook. When I open a main.tex file, I notice that the major mode is latex-mode and my hooked configurations are not activated. I have to M-x Tex-latex-mode to activate them. But the major-mode is still latex-mode.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()

        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        ;; auctex

        (setq TeX-auto-save t)
        (setq TeX-parse-self t)
       ))
```

So I would like to know what is the difference of these modes and how can I turn on AUCTeX automatically when I open a *.tex file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The modes provided by AUCTeX are listed at https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Modes-and-Hooks and they are

- `plain-TeX-mode`
- `LaTeX-mode`
- `ams-TeX-mode`
- `ConTeXt-mode`
- `Texinfo-mode`
- `docTeX-mode`

Instead,

- `tex-mode`
- `plain-tex-mode`
- `latex-mode`
- `slitex-mode`
- `doctex-mode`

(note the different capitalization) are the major modes provided by the [TeX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/TeX-Mode.html) package shipped with Emacs.

If you want to open all `*.tex` files with AUCTeX LaTeX mode add this to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tex$" . LaTeX-mode))
```

Actually, this shouldn't be necessary, because AUCTeX defines the `tex-mode.el` mode names as alias of its own modes.

Comment: I think this information is outdated. `LaTeX-mode` seems to be an alias of `latex-mode`, and `TeX-latex-mode` is a mode defined by AUCTeX (version 12.3). Anyways, I am completely confused. If i want to set keybindings, which map do I use: `latex-mode-map` or `LaTeX-mode-map` or both?

Comment: After digging a bit deeper, it seems that AUCTeX is overriding the alias of `LaTeX-mode`, but I can't see where ... I wonder why this is so complicated.

Comment: For your keybindings you should use only `LaTeX-mode-map`, which is the official AUCTeX name.

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation of `TeX-latex-mode`, which seems to be what the OP originally asked about. `LaTeX-mode` does not have a docstring, whereas `TeX-latex-mode` is documented as being the `Major mode in AUCTeX for editing LaTeX files.`

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Use `latex-mode` or `LaTeX-mode` (they mean the same thing), no need to change `auto-mode-alist`, and use `LaTeX-mode-hook` for hooking into AucTeX.

Setting up AucTeX can be quite confusing, because it uses [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) to override Emacs' built-in support for TeX and friends.

So, after installing AucTeX from ELPA, you should see the following in `C-h f latex-mode`:

```
This function has :override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’.
```

Same for all the other tex modes, though the list of modes that AucTeX overrides depends on the value of the `TeX-modes` variable.

The function `LaTeX-mode` is not defined in AucTeX (any more?): it's defined in core Emacs, with a cryptic comment about compatibility:

```
;; The following three autoloaded aliases appear to conflict with
;; AUCTeX.  However, even though AUCTeX uses the mixed case variants
;; for all mode relevant variables and hooks, the invocation function
;; and setting of `major-mode' themselves need to be lowercase for
;; AUCTeX to provide a fully functional user-level replacement.  So
;; these aliases should remain as they are, in particular since AUCTeX
;; users are likely to use them.
;; Note from Stef: I don't understand the above explanation, the only
;; justification I can find to keep those confusing aliases is for those
;; users who may have files annotated with -*- LaTeX -*- (e.g. because they
;; received them from someone using AUCTeX).

;;;###autoload
(defalias 'TeX-mode #'tex-mode)
;;;###autoload
(defalias 'plain-TeX-mode #'plain-tex-mode)
;;;###autoload
(defalias 'LaTeX-mode #'latex-mode)
```

What this all means is that, at least in 2021, you do *not* need to change `auto-mode-alist` to use AucTeX; just installing it is enough for it to override Emacs' builtin functionality.

Unfortunately, there's one last source of confusion.  Even though `LaTeX-mode` is now mostly just a useless alias for `latex-mode`, it turns out that code in AucTeX that overrides `latex-mode` does *not* call `latex-mode-hook` (it calls `LaTeX-mode-hook`, which is different.  So the `LaTeX-` variables, which are the AucTeX ones (as opposed to the lowercase ones that are builtin with Emacs), are still useful.